# Создать папку в папке Music

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать папку в стандартной папке Music в памяти телефона? Мой код создает папку testdir в папке Music не в корне а в папке `Android/data/app/files/Music/testdir.`

```
File direct = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + File.separator + "testdir");
```

Comment: А чем вас это не устраивает? Скорее всего нельзя просто так папки где хочется создавать.

Comment: Я хочу создавать в корне устройства. Так File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName); создается, но этот метод устарел. Поэтому хотелось исправить код.

Comment: Это не будет работать на Андроид 10 и выше, на 8-9 скорее всего тоже..

Comment: Сейчас у меня стоит условие использовать этот кусок кода из комментария выше до Android 10. Но он устарел и хотелось бы использовать актуальные конструкции.